# Variables not updated from within baseHTTPserver class

Tags: python, variables, basehttpserver

I am trying to build a simple web server, that receives GPS coordinates through POST requests and then shows them on a webpage. 
I receive just fine the coordinates from my phone, it prints them to the server window so i understand that the variables 'lat' and 'lon' should have been updated with the actual coordinates, but when i open my browser i only get "test test"..
Sorry for my noob question, but I am very new to python and I cannot understand why the class MyHandler can't access the variables..
This is my code so far:

```
PORT = 5050
lat="test"
lon="test"
speed="test"


def serv_responseGET(s):
    s.send_response(200)
    s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    s.end_headers()
    s.wfile.write(lat, lon)

def serv_responsePOST(s):       
    s.send_response(200)
    s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    s.end_headers()
    s.wfile.write(' ');

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(s):
        print s.path
        length = int(s.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = urlparse.parse_qs(s.rfile.read(length).decode('utf-8'))
        for key, value in post_data.iteritems():
            if key=="lat":
                lat=''.join(value)
            if key=="lon":
                lon=''.join(value)
            if key=="speed":
                speed=''.join(value)
        print datetime.datetime.now()
        print "lat=", lat 
        print "lon=", lon
        print "spd=", speed
        serv_responsePOST(s)


    def do_GET(s):
        print s.path
        serv_responseGET(s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class(('', PORT), MyHandler)
    print time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % ('', PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

and this is what i get on python window after a POST from my phone:

```
/
2014-10-25 16:23:20.598733
lat= 37.971649
lon= 23.727053
spd= 0.0
192.168.2.50 - - [25/Oct/2014 16:23:20] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, when you assign to a variable inside a procedure, it assumes you meant to create a local variable and ignores the global variables.  To assign to global variables, you need to declare them first.  so just add the line

```
global lat, lon, speed
```

To the start of your do_POST and I believe that will fix it.